# Preventing user from duplicate data entry

Tags: c#, sql, database

This is a student management system,which a defined admin can add/remove students and stuff but the thing is i can't prevent user from adding a student with same id/email.There were other posts but i couldn't get it to work.I want to give error message to user when he tries to input already existing values.Thanks for help.

```
    private void populateGrid()
    {
        string query = "SELECT studentId,fname,lname,email,phone FROM student";

        using (connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, connection))
        using (SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(command))
        {

            var dersler = new DataTable();
            adapter.Fill(dersler);

            bindingSource1.DataSource = dersler;
            dataGridView1.DataSource = bindingSource1;
        }
    }

    private void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string query ="INSERT INTO student(studentId,fname,lname,email,phone) VALUES (@studentIdVal,@fnameVal,@lnameVal,@emailVal,@phoneVal)";
        string query1 = "INSERT INTO loginusers(username,upassword) VALUES (@emailVal,@phoneVal)";
        using (connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, connection))
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query1, connection))
        {
            connection.Open();
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@emailVal", txtEmail.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@phoneVal", txtPhone.Text);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@studentIdVal", txtStudentId.Text);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fnameVal", txtFname.Text);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@lnameVal", txtLname.Text);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@emailVal", txtEmail.Text);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@phoneVal", txtPhone.Text);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            populateGrid();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Have a look at `Merge` command which either *insert* data (if record doesn't exist) or *update* existing record.

Comment: Check if other record exists with the same email before insert

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> i can't prevent user from adding a student with same id/email

Why not? You can `ALTER` your table and add a `UNIQUE` key or constraint on those columns which will make sure only unique data is present on that column and trying to insert duplicate data will throw a SQL Exception at your application code which you can handle accordingly.

You can either define unique key on individual column like `unique(id)` and `unique(email)` or combination of those column `unique(id, email)`

Comment: i altered the table and made id,email unique but now there is an error saying  Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint,Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.student' when i input duplicate data.@rahul

Comment: @PoyrazKürkçüoğlu, exactly that's what you needed. That exception tells you that you are trying to insert dups and thus you can handle the exception and show any validation message to end user

Comment: okay i made a try catch block with a code MessageBox.Show(ex.Message); my last question is how do i show the message i want to user ? @rahul

Comment: 1. Decide on the message you want.  2. Pass it as an argument to `MessageBox.Show`.  *It's crazy enough, it just may work*.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the procedure for figuring this out.

1. Ensure there is a uniqueness constraint on the database table
2. Add a database transaction around the execution of `cmd` and `command` so you can't save one without the other (this is very important).
3. Compile your code, run it, and attempt to save a duplicate
4. Observe the sort of exception that is raised
5. Add a try/catch block around the transaction, catching the exception that you noted in step 4.

Comment: it worked out but i want to show a spesific message to user when exception is catched.Is there a way to edit the ex.message for showing to user  ? @JohnWu

Comment: Maybe post another question on Stackoverflow.  In general you should not be displaying `exception.Message` to an end user.

Answer (score -2):

check email exist before insert

```
SELECT studentId FROM student where email=@emailVal
```

if record found show error message otherwise insert record

Comment: This is not 100% reliable unless the SQL is moved into a stored procedure along with the insert, wrapped in a transaction, and `serializable` locking semantics are specified.  Otherwise, someone on another connection could add the record just after you have checked for it and just before you do the actual insert.

Comment: @JohnWu thanks for explaining why this was a bad way to go with